# Pandoc template: different separator for last item

Tags: templates, pandoc

I'm writing a custom Pandoc template and want it to print a list of authors so that all authors are separated with ", " except for the last author who instead is separated with an "and". Can this be done?

Let's say this is my template:

```
$if(title)$
$title$
$endif$
$if(author)$
$for(author)$$author$$sep$, $endfor$
$endif$
$body$
```

Which outputs:

```
My title
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
Document body
```

But I want it to output:

```
My title
Author 1, Author 2 and Author 3
Document body
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @cderv Sorry, I did not. Please post if you do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use so-called "pipes" from Pandoc template syntax (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

We'll make a for loop for all-but-last items in our array (`it` is considered as a pronoun inside the loop, refering to the values from `authors/allbutlast`). For those elements of our `authors` array, we'll use ", " as a separator, but *outside* the loop, we'll simply put the "final separator" ("and" in this case), and the last element of `authors` array (`~` stands for unbreakable space, if you are going to output to LaTeX).

```
$for(authors/allbutlast)$$it$$sep$, $endfor$ and~$authors/last$
```

EDIT:
In case there's only one author, use something like this:

```
$if(author/allbutlast)$
$for (author/allbutlast)$
${it}$sep$, 
$endfor$
and ${author/last}
$else$
${author/last}
$endif$
```

Comment: This solution works well if there is always more than one author. 

But if the array only has a single item it will add 'and' in front of the only author, as it is both the first and last item in the array.

Comment: @NickBarreto answer edited to include this case.

Comment: Amazing. I was toying around with some ifs to try and get a solution like this but hadn't quite managed. Will try this out as soon as I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: The edited answer doesn't work for me (pandoc 3.1.6). The starting conditional evaluates as true even when there's only one author, and I get the same name twice with "and" in between.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Jan's answer a little to get it to work in my use-case (a Quarto template). Why do I have `by-author`? Not sure, but that is what the Quarto template I am changing uses.

```
    $if(by-author/allbutlast)$
    $for(by-author/allbutlast)$
    {\large{$by-author.name.literal$}}$sep$, 
    $endfor$
    $for(by-author/last)$
    {and \large{$by-author.name.literal$}}
    $endfor$
    $else$
    ${by-author/last}
    $endif$
```

Here is my full use case. I know this is way more than what was asked, but if you end up on this answer and are making pandoc templates, this might be helpful. I've learned a lot from seeing full use cases. I am working on a title page template for a Quarto book.

YAML `_quarto.yml`

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: The title
  subtitle: The subtitle
  author:
    - name: Jane Doe
    - name: Eva Nováková
    - name: Matti Meikäläinen
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - chap1.qmd
    - chap2.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrbook
    template-partials: ["partials/before-body.tex"]
    toc: true
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % logo
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % international characters
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % international characters
        \usepackage{hyphenat} % don't hyphenate the title
        \usepackage{authblk}
```

`partials/before-body.tex`

```
\begin{frontmatter} % why not titlepage? dunno, titlepage threw errors.

    \raggedleft % Right align the title page
    
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.85\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page
    
        {\large\bfseries\nohyphens{$title$}}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title
        $if(subtitle)$
        {\large\textit{$subtitle$}}\\[4\baselineskip] % Subtitle
        $endif$
        
        $if(by-author/allbutlast)$
        $for(by-author/allbutlast)$
        {\large{$by-author.name.literal$}}$sep$, 
        $endfor$
        $for(by-author/last)$
        {and \large{$by-author.name.literal$}}
        $endfor$
        $else$
        ${by-author/last}
        $endif$
        
        \vspace{0.5\textheight} % Whitespace
        
        {\noindent The Publisher~~\plogo}\\[\baselineskip] % Publisher+logo
    }

\end{frontmatter}
```

[image: title page]